# How to list all commands related to a specific extension in VS Code's command palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension and I would like to know if there is a way to list all the commands that belong to my extension in the command palette.

I have added an item in the status bar that once clicked should ideally list all the commands available from my extension in the command palette, similar to when you click on the language, a list of languages shows up.

The closest thing I could get is this:

```js
    const statusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem();
    statusBar.text = 'Cloudflare';
    statusBar.command = 'cloudflareDevTools.commands';
    statusBar.show();

    let commands = vscode.commands.registerCommand('cloudflareDevTools.commands', () => {

        vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.quickOpen", ">Cloudflare");

    });
```

Which results in this:

[image]

This way I'm basically filtering the commands in the command palette by providing a string that's part of the extension's name, and it kinda works as it shows all the commands from my extension, but you can see how it's not ideal in case multiple extensions have a similar name.

There's something similar when you go in the settings: you can provide `@ext:kenhowardpdx.vscode-gist` and this will list all the settings related to that specific extension. I would like something similar but for the commands I've registered in `package.json` and `extension.js`.

Thank you!

Comment: I take it you do not have a consistent command `category` that you could use for all commands, like `Cloudflare:` Note the `:` to delimit your category.  That seems to work.

Comment: @Mark thank you! You're right `category` will get me a lot closer and I'll go for that for now, but surely any other extension could accidentally use the same category, screwing things up. I was wondering if there's an API point that allows me to feed all the extension's commands to the QuickPick, but this will do for the time being thanks again

Comment: Do you have any commands that are not in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this before.  You can show a QuickPick, basically a mini-Command Palette, with only commands you have filtered.

```js
const qpOptions = {title: "commands from the find-and-transform extension", canPickMany: false};

const allCommands = await vscode.commands.getCommands(true);

// filter by your extensionID
const findExtensionCommands = allCommands.filter(command => command.startsWith('find-and-transform'));

const selectedCommand = await vscode.window.showQuickPick(findExtensionCommands, qpOptions);

if (selectedCommand) {
    // do whatever you are going to do if the user makes a selection, like
    // vscode.commands.executeCommand(selectedCommand);
    console.log(selectedCommand);
}
```

You can also make QuickPickItems out of the commands, so that you can add descriptions to them for example.